# Does "aptitude search '~U'" require "aptitude update" to display correct information?

Tags: package-management, updates, aptitude

As the title says:
If I run `aptitude search '~U’` do I need to run `aptitude update` before in order to get the correct results?

The [aptitude documentation](http://aptitude.alioth.debian.org/doc/en/ch02s04s05.html) says:

> ?upgradable | ~U | Select packages that are installed and can be upgraded.

However I'm not sure if this only searches the cache or the repos the packages come from.

I need this for some sort of update notifier which is called by cron regularly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**

`aptitude search '~U'` requires `aptitude update` to display correct information.

---

You should run

```
sudo aptitude update
```

to get actually information. The command

```
sudo aptitude search '~U'
```

doesn't search online, only local in your system.

It's not necessary on RPM based system with `yum upgrade`, `dnf upgrade`, `yum distro-sync` and `dnf distro-sync`.

Comment: Thank you. Now I need to rethink my script since it obviously needs root to call `aptitude update` whereas `aptitude search` was possible without root permissions. But I'm sure I'll find a way.

Comment: You could change your `sudoers` like `%users ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/aptitude`

Comment: I'm not sure if I really want to do something like this. I think of running the script from the roots crontab. No workarounds are needed then and I can even notify every user on the system which seems better than my initial idea. 

For clarification: the script simply searches for available updates and shows them to the user via a notification on the desktop.

Comment: yes, roots crontab a better idea.